# how to create a method that return true or false based on a record count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a method that return either true or false.

Here is what I have

**View**

```
<%= @poll.has_user_voted?(current_user) %>
```

**Model**

```
  def has_user_voted?(user)
    voted = self.poll_votes.where(:user_id => user.id).length

    return !voted
  end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong. It's returning nothing blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is true in Ruby except `nil` and `false,` which means that `0` is actually *true.*

Try something like:

```
  def has_user_voted?(user)
    self.poll_votes.where(:user_id => user.id).length > 0
  end
```

This is just an example, I presume that you also want the vote so your real-life version will make use of `poll_votes,` if not, you might want to just use `#count`.

Comment: very nice. changing the == to > did the trick. Thank you ross

Comment: As noted in mine and Luke's answer, returning a whole result set here is needlessly inefficient. You should use `exists?` or `count` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a pretty efficient method:

```
def has_user_voted?(user)
  self.poll_votes.exists?(['user_id = ?', "%#{user.id}%"])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if there are any matching records you should use the built-in `count` method instead of needlessly retrieving a bunch of rows and instantiating all those objects. e.g.:

```
def has_user_voted? user
  poll_votes.where(:user_id => user.id).count > 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another slight technicality to note:

def has_user_voted? user
  poll_votes.where(:user_id => user.id).size > 0
end

.size will either issue a db .count, or if the association is already loaded, it will get the length of the array and not even do a sql call.  I always use size.